# Sending IM from Skype Web SDK to UCMA Bot

Tags: skype, ucma, skypedeveloper

I am unable to send IM from Skype Web SDK to UCMA bot endpoint. Same code works if I login as SfB desktop client user. Will Skype Web SDK supports connecting with UCMA ? Please help.

Thanks,

Suresh.

Comment: Hi Suresh,

The Skype Web SDK actually uses UCWA, so there should be no issues.  

Are the endpoints your using for the Skype Web SDK and UCWA on the same  domain?

If not, make sure the domains are federated so that there are able to communicate?  

Also, is the Skype Web SDK returning any errors?

Regards,

Matthew

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am using same UCMA UserEndpoint for both UCWA and Skype Web SDK. When I initiate a conversation directly from UCWA to the userendpoint, I am getting new conversation request in my UCMA application. But not when I do from Skype Web SDK. I tried your Skype SDK example 
https://www.matthewproctor.com/skype-web-sdk-sending-an-instant-message 

But, if I login into Skype4B Desktop Client with the same Userpoint credentials, I am getting Toast message. I am wondering what could be the issue?

Comment: Your sample gives me this error:
Error:Error: The remote party didn’t respond. Please wait and try again.

But you code works well when I login in Skype4B desktop client.

Comment: Firstly, you typically can't send a message between the same endpoint - that's effectively sending a message to yourself in the client. :-)

Comment: Secondly, you (or your user) needs to accept the toast message that pops up - the message won't be delivered if the toast is rejected or ignored. That's the default behaviour of Lync / Skype for Business.

Comment: I am not sending mesaage to same endpoint its differnt one. I am sending message from abc@domain.com logged in web sdk to the ucma userendpoint def@domain.com

Comment: Matthew - any other thoughts on this? Do you have any working sample for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the sample downloaded from https://www.matthewproctor.com/skype-web-sdk-sending-an-instant-message didnt worked for me. I downloaded the samples provided in msdn site and it worked.

Thanks Mathew Proctor for your help.